# Extract information from Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have information stored in structure array with dtype as time, x, y,x and cnt.

```
 time              x                y                 z       cnt
 41641            1428              0                 3      2554
 42152            1428              0                 3      2554
 42602            1428              0                 3      2554
 43627            1428              1                 3      2554
 44075            1428              0                 3      2555
 44552            1428              1                 3      2555
 44901            1428              1                 3      2556
 45377            1428              0                 3      2557
 45889            1428              0                 3      2557
 46519            1428              0                 3      2557
 47680            1428              1                 3      2557
 48056            1428              0                 3      2558
 48416            1428              0                 3      2558
 49270            1428              1                 3      2558
```

I want to extract the 1st row from each of the repeated cnt parameter:

```
 41641            1428              0                 3      2554
 44075            1428              0                 3      2555
 44901            1428              1                 3      2556
 45377            1428              0                 3      2557
 48056            1428              0                 3      2558
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What does not work?

Comment: As you work with structured arrays you might want to have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

if your data array is called `data`:

```
print data[np.unique(data[:,4],return_index=True)[1]]

#[[41641  1428     0     3  2554]
# [44075  1428     0     3  2555]
# [44901  1428     1     3  2556]
# [45377  1428     0     3  2557]
# [48056  1428     0     3  2558]]
```

Comment: Thanks. This one liner worked it's charm after converting structured array to numpy.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.unique` with `return_index=True` will give you a list of indices to take from.  Try something like this (VERY UNTESTED) attempt.

```
cnt = structArray['cnt']
uniq = numpy.unique(cnt, return_index=True)
result = structArray[uniq]
```

Of course you can collapse this into a one-liner.